# Cannot create the same file again

Tags: java, file

I have a class that represents a document as a directory and any document page as a single file. With constructor I create all the files in the directory. I have a method to replace a file content with its new version. I tried to delete it and then to recreate it with methods of Java class File but it gives me an exception.

I run it on windows 10 using eclipse.

I successfully create a file with another name in the same directory with the same method.

I tried to call the method setWritable() of Java class File after delete old file and before create the new file but it returns me false.

I tried Files.delete(f.toPath()) but it doesn't give any exception

here's the code:

```
synchronized(sync) {
    File f=new File(docPath+section+".txt");
    try{
        f.delete();
        f.createNewFile(); //this line give me the exception
        //write new version on the file
        FileChannel out=FileChannel.open(Paths.get(docPath+section+".txt"), StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
        while (modifiedSection.hasRemaining())
            out.write(modifiedSection);
        modifiedSection.clear();
        out.close();
        }
 }
```

This is the exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Access denied
at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
at java.io.File.createNewFile(Unknown Source)
at Server.Document.endEditSection(Document.java:134)
at Server.Test.run(Test.java:29)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Propably you did not close the same file, somewhere else in the code. f.delete() will return a boolean value whether file deleted or not. You can check also with Files.delete(f.toPath()), it will throw AccessDeniedException in the case of failure.

Comment: no, the delete() returns true

Answer (score 0):

Probably a permission issue.

Please check if f.delete() is returning false. In that case the file is still there and you cannot recreate it anew.

Tested with this snippet

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File f = new File("c:\\a.txt"); //new file in a readonly location
    f.delete(); //it returns false, so the file is still there
    f.createNewFile(); //throws Access denied exception
}
```